# Jenkins MultiJob does not start any downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a very simple MultiJob project in Jenkins. It has one MultiJob phase with one job (obviously the idea is to add more in the future).

When I run the MultiJob, it queues the phase job - but never starts it.

The multi job simply says its in progress and the phase job remains as pending.

And ideas whats wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your downstream job is set to build on a particular slave that is not online/available or set to build on a tag not served by any slaves. In any case check whether you can build your job standalone first.

Comment: Thanks, but the individual jobs work ok. If I add a build step "Trigger/call builds on other projects", I can run the projects. But they run in parallel - which is not what I want.